# Agregar Pollyfill en Next JS para mostrar vistas en Internet Explore

Tags: reactjs, aplicación-web, internet-explorer, next.js, polyfill

Estoy desarrollando una webapp con Next JS y necesito mostrar una vista en particular cuando los usuarios acceden a la web desde internet explore. estoy usando una librería (react-device-detect) y con eso logro detectar que el usuario esta desde internet explore, pero la vista no se renderiza, queda todo en blanco y si hago un console.log de la función que detecta si esta usando IE, me trae un "true" que eso significa que si esta detectando el navegador. Estuve leyendo algo sobre definir o crear polyfill, pero la verdad no entiendo nada y tampoco hay algo en concreto sobre este tema en especifico, hablan de agregar algo al next.config.js pero cuando lo hago no funciona, si alguien puede iluminarme seria de gran ayuda.Adjunto imagen de la vista que intento mostrar en IE.
[![Vista para IE][1]][1].

````
 const BlockIE = () => {
     const linksLabelInfo = ['Google Chrome', 'Microsoft Edge', 
 'Firefox'];
     const hrefInfo = [
         'https://www.google.com/chrome/',
         'https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/edge',
         'https://www.mozilla.org/es-MX/',
     ];

    const onClickResult: Function[] = [
        () => window.open(hrefInfo[0], '_blank'),
        () => window.open(hrefInfo[1], '_blank'),
        () => window.open(hrefInfo[2], '_blank'),
    ];

    const onKeyPressResult = (event: KeyboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === ' ') {
            onClickResult;
        }
    };

    return (
        <DesktopWrapper headTitle=''>
            <Header title={''} hideBackButton />
            <WithLinks
                title={'Este navegador ya no está soportado'}
                description={`Por favor, usa uno de los navegadores soportados:`}
                linksLabel={linksLabelInfo}
                href={hrefInfo}
                onClick={onClickResult}
                onKeyPress={onKeyPressResult}
            />
        </DesktopWrapper>
    );
};```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTvuo.png
````

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Por otro lado, le hace falta un [mcve]. Una imagen no nos dice nada y no podemos adivinar a partir de ella cuál es el contenido del código que no se despliega en Internet Explorer. Te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahí agregue el componente entero de la vista que quiero mostrar, nose que mas agregar, tal vez como tengo configurado el archivo nexts.config.js?